# SQL server and PHP - specify datetime format

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with `datetime` columns. In SQL Server Management Studio, I can see the date in  `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MMMM` format, but when I select the data with PHP [mssql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php), I get something like this - `srp  1 2014 12:00:00:000` (instead of `2014-08-01 12:00:00.000`).

Is there a way to change the datetime format? (I don't want to parse the localized datetime in PHP.)

Comment: SQL Server does not have a default format for displaying datetime values. If you want to display them in a certain format this should be done in the front end. What you are seeing in SSMS is how that front end formats datetime values.

Comment: look here http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution...

```
ini_set("mssql.datetimeconvert", "Off");
```

It turns off the localized datetime formatting in mssql extension and now I get the datetime as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, which is suitable for me.